# Grails GET method for JSON

Tags: json, grails, get, titanium

I am trying to use the http GET method to retrieve JSON object I have created, then in Titanium I have created a method to retrieve, however it is only retrieving "undefined"

```
def listJSON() {
   def converter = User.list() as JSON
   System.out.println(converter)
   render(converter)
   //response(converter)
}
```

The output from grails is correct and the page rendered (from system out) :

```
[{"class":"testingmobile.User","id":1,"age":22,"email":"test@hotmail.com","name":"Ryan","occupation":"Whatever "}]
```

The code from the mobile app in Titanium is as follows:

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/TestingMobile/user/listJSON";
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient ({
onload : function(e) {
    Ti.API.info("Recieved text: "+ this.responceText);
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    getShow(jsonObj);
    alert('success');
},
onerror : function(e) {
    Ti.API.debug(e.error);
    alert('error');
},
timeout : 5000 
});
client.open("GET", url);
client.send();
```

The console outputs "Received text: undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`responceText`

should be

`responseText`

with an **s**, not a **c**.